# Нужна ли запятая с тире?

Tags: запятые

Хабиб, более известный как Абу Таммам(,) — поэт эпохи аббасидов.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данной фразе определительный оборот *более известный как Абу Таммам* стоит после определяемого им существительного *Хабиб*. Поэтому, согласно "Правилам русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup>:

> §46.1. Определительный оборот, стоящий после определяемого существительного, выделяется или отделяется запятыми.

Тире, в свою очередь, ставится между подлежащим *Хабиб* и сказуемым *поэт*, выраженными существительными в именительном падеже:

> §10. Между подлежащим и именным сказуемым на месте отсутствующей связки ставится тире, если подлежащее и сказуемое выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа.

Поскольку оба знака обусловлены различными правилами, то их сочетание диктуется следующим правилом:

> §156. При сочетании в тексте тире и запятой вначале ставится запятая (запятая закрывает впереди стоящую конструкцию), затем тире.

Получаем:

*Хабиб, более известный как Абу Таммам, — поэт эпохи аббасидов.*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.